# RosActivity with Google Maps Android API, UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION

Tags: ros, rosandroid, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all.

I trying to use an activity which uses the  *Google Maps Android API*  alongside with a RosActivity. But I end up with an error like this:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':maps:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
/home/cburger/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/dx --dex --output /home/cburger/myandroid/src/android_foo/maps/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/home/cburger/myandroid/src/android_foo/maps/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
Error Code:
2
Output:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

I tried to solve it by adding

```
defaultConfig {
    ....
    multiDexEnabled = true
 }
```

to build.gradle according to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497553/build-tools-21-1-2-unexpected-top-level-exception), but that didn't work and gives me this *Application Installation Failed* error

```
Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER.
```

my Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
compile 'org.ros.android_core:android_10:[0.2,0.3)'
compile 'org.ros.android_core:android_15:[0.2,0.3)'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'    //used for the google maps API
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:[15.,)'         //used for the google maps API
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled = true
  }
}
```

has anyone done this before or any hints on how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222522/rosactivity-with-google-maps-android-api,-unexpected-top-level-exception/) by [Christoph0000](https://answers.ros.org/users/25330/christoph0000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-12-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First
add this  to defaultConfig:

```
defaultConfig { 

        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true

}
```

Second
add this  to dependencies:

```
dependencies{

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile 'com.github.rosjava.android_remocons:common_tools:[0.2,0.3)'
    compile 'org.ros.android_core:android_15:[0.2,0.3)'
}
```

That's all.

Refer to URL:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library

---

Originally posted by [Tony10012](https://answers.ros.org/users/27331/tony10012/) with karma: 56 on 2016-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0